# How native English speakers perceive IT company and domain names by ear?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I want to create web service and have bought domain name which for me, native Russian, looks good. But I have a question about how native English speakers perceive that name by ear?

The name is `distractless.me` and `distractless.email`.

1. First, I wanted to have association with adjective ending on -less, like `painless`. But it looks like there is no such word and only `12,100` Google search results. Otherwise `less distract` has `24,800,000` search results and correction that I would probably wanted `less distracted` with `43,900,000` results.
2. Second, I wanted the people would directly understand service goal by domain name (service clean up and manage burden of clutter email box)

These are my summarized questions:

1. How do you fill that domain name? Does it have some hidden undesired
   meaning or association or like that?
2. How do you feel the general IT company (and domain) names, like `Facebook`?

For me, native Russian, if I'd see service with these direct Russian names (face; book) that would only cause confusion because it's very weird and unnatural hearing, unlike English pronunciation `Facebook` doesn't have that association and looks like abstract and doesn't have that hidden meanings (just abstract company name)

Comment: You need to hire a consultant and writer.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, definitely for content. But I'm asking for about general native speakers perception.

Comment: Facebook is not just an abstract company name; it's a book of faces (a college year book, showing faces and names of students). *Distractless* doesn't really work because *distract* is not a noun.

Comment: Man, this kind of questions sure seems to be popular these days. The site policy is to close them all as subjective, likem. But my personal two cents are pretty much always the same: It sounds horrible, made up, and stupid (and in your case, as Andrew has pointed out, morphologically broken), but none of that matters. It's a name. It can be anything you like. It does not have a meaning. It is a label. Nobody cares if you call your domain distractless, or google, or apple, or wii. It is just a label. And if anything, the funnier-sounding it is, the more attention you will get for free.

Comment: I perceive that name by ear [ahem] to be ridiculous.

Comment: Facebook is a type of neologism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Distractless" sounds a little odd to my ear. "Undistracted" is an actual word and sounds much more natural; it also implies the undoing or reversal of distraction, rather than the mere lack of distraction. And your service, of course, is about actively **un**doing the **distract**ion caused by a cluttered inbox.
2. I'd say they're so deeply ingrained that I perceive them as words in and of themselves, rather than compound words formed by their individual components. When I hear or see "Facebook", I don't think of faces and books, I think of blue and heart reacts and profile pics and messaging.